# Why am I getting "OperationalError: No Such Table" in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to store values in an sqlite database and them pull them from the database to use on my project using django models. There are two applications in my django project: 'main' and 'apply.' I have run migrate and makemigrations for both. When I save values to the model fields for 'main' it works fine. However, when I try to save values to the model fields for 'apply', I always get "utils.OperationalError: No Such Table apply_(model name)" I have set up a different database for my 'apply' models and the 'main' models use the default database.

Relevant settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },

    'apply': {
        'NAME': 'apply_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['django_webpage_project.routers.ApplyRouter']
```

projectname/routers.py

```
class ApplyRouter:
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth and contenttypes applications.
"""
route_app_labels = {'apply',}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'apply'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'apply'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
    involved.
    """
    if (
        obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
        obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
    ):
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
    'auth_db' database.
    """
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db == 'apply'
    return None
```

main/models

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    #age = models.IntegerField(default=0)


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

apply/models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Frye(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name} 
{self.age} {self.height} {self.occupation}'

class Homer(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   age = models.IntegerField()
   height = models.CharField(max_length=9)
   occupation = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name} 
{self.age} {self.height} {self.occupation}'


class Holt(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name} 
    {self.age} {self.height} {self.occupation}'
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think it is DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.ApplyRouter'] if you have a "__init__.py" inside your routers folder.

Comment: Have you run migration? `makemigration` and `migrate`

Comment: Yes, I have run both. Even when I run sqlmigrate it shows that the tables exist